# Apex field update to match workflow criteria. Field gets updated but workflow doesn't queue up

Tags: apex, workflow, time-dependent-workflow

When I manually `edit and save` the record to `match a criteria` that `activates a time based workflow`, the actions are queued up as expected in the time based monitor workflow.

But when apex updates fields and then the corresponding record with a matching criteria, the time based workflow is not being queued at all. The field is updated properly. But the workflow never gets queued.

Any idea on what's going on and how to tackle it?

Here's an example where both the fields are set correctly by `Apex`, but the `workflow` is never queued up. Am I missing something?

**Apex:**

```
Case.StatusReport__c = 'Somevalue'
Case.StatusTimeSetOn = System.now();
update Case;
```

**Time Based Workflow:**

```
Criteria: When Case.StatusReport__c = 'Somevalue'
1 hour after Case.StatusTimeSetOn
Action: Update Case.StatusREport__c ='Anothervalue'
```

Answer (score 2):

Sigh. Found the solution finally.

All I had to do was check "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" on the field update associated with the workflow.